# xrandr scaling issues of 4k Monitor combined with a HD Monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, xrandr

Currently i run this command to get everything correct scaled:

```
xrandr --output DP-2 --fb 7680x2160 --mode 3840x2160 --scale 1x1 --pos 0x0 --primary \
       --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 2x2 --pos 3840x0
```

but the problem is that desktop stays in the 1920 x 1080 format... i can easily drag now windows do the other screen that are nicely scaled but my desktop does not get bigger [as you can see in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWA8O.png)

Does somebody know something what i can do to get this working or do i need to scale my 4k display down?

Thank you very much in advance! :D

Here my current configuration:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 7680 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 3840x2160+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      74.98    59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DP-2 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 607mm x 345mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
```

Hardware Configuration:

- GPU: NVIDIA Geforce RTX 2070
  Kernel:
  Linux 5.15.105-1

Comment: You have asked a video related question but I do not see the version of Ubuntu in your question, the video card involved or the driver being used. Please use edit and add this critical info to the question. Please do not put the info in a comment.

Comment: Could you try adding `--virtual 7680x2160` to `xrandr --output DP-2 --fb 7680x2160 --etc...` This will set the size of the desktop pane for the DP-2 (4K) output to 7680x2160 pixels, making it fill the full screen. Then your icons, windows, etc should scale to fit. Also, make sure to enable desktop scaling system-wide. Open System Settings -> Display. Go to the "Resolution" tab and check the box next to "Allow scaling of screen contents". This will make the entire desktop scale when you set the monitor resolutions. You can reply if it doens't work.

Comment: Hi there thank you for your advice! I tried it with the --virtual but xrandr has no parameter --virtual. And i need to say that i currently use Manjaro and i could not find any setting of "Allow scaling of screen contents" under Display. I really didnt know how to help myself... Maybe you have another ideas?